# How to draw a grid line at 0.75 and 2.1 on parallel to horizontal axis in gnu-plot script

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script that gives me 2x2 array of plot.

I want to draw below two grid lines in each the sub plot.

```
set arrow 100 from 1e17, 0.75 to 1e21, 0.75 nohead ls 100 front
set arrow 100 from 1e17, 2.1 to 1e21, 2.1 nohead ls 100 front
```

Using above arrows, I get only a line at 2.1 and line at 0.75 is missing.

How I can get these two lines in each sub-plot?

Comment: Your second command overrides the first one.  Both define an arrow with id 100.   Change the second command to define an arrow with a different is, maybe 101.